# SSIS multiple redirect single file in dataflow

Tags: redirect, ssis, rows

I am having some challenges being new to multi-step data flows in SSIS, but here's my situation.  I know what I want to do, but I can only seem to find good examples of a single redirect.  I have a multistep workflow with a few lookups that may fail based on customer provided data that may not exist.  I don't want the entire process to fail, but instead, what I am trying to do is take a "waterfall" approach.  The first lookup to fail would redirect the row to an output or be kept somewhere in a "holding tank"...then the second one would fail and the same thing would happen.  I want to rollup all the failing rows into one flat file with the columns intact so it can be reprocessed as a source flat file again.

Any help would be appreciated on what the best approach to take on this problem would be since I have multiple workflows that would benefit from capturing rows for reprocessing.

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow must show what you have tried and why it didnt work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: The *LookUp* component has just that. You can redirect *no match* records to an output. Then *Union All* the no match outputs and put it into a *Flat File Destination*. Bear in mind that SO is a Q&A site for *programming* questions. *Programming ideas* questions are Off-Topic and can be closed.

Comment: I think the Union All approach is what I was looking for since I didn't know how to feed all of the failures step by step into a single source.  Thank you for your feedback and I will bear your comment in mind next time I post.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your package architecture it's hard to diagnose fully, but I believe there are a few ways to approach this depending on what's failing and how the data is being passed down the pipeline (ie. bulk load vs row by row). That being said, it sounds like you would benefit from creating a single sql table for these items. Having multiple processes trying to write to a single file could cause problems, nor do you want to try to read all the files and construct a new file from the many. Each segment of the process would be able to write to the table as needed and in the end you have your full list of rows to be reprocessed. Also, I'm not sure if this is feasible or not, but if you can pre-process the file to determine which rows don't have your look-up values then you could just write the rows ahead of time to prevent the package from failing. That would make your package more robust. Also, you can set up your lookup tasks to not fail if the values aren't there. This allows the items to be processed, but may be missing the lookup values. Without knowing your situation, I'm not sure if that's an acceptable outcome or not...but those are a few of the options.